Rows of repeating '^@' in the terminal after startup
Allwinner H3, openwrt ("machine"). Connected to terminal RPi through TTL RX/TX serial port.
Terminal made of RPi is connected to the abovementioned machine. Yesterday I logged out, and shut down the Pi. Today I came back, powered up the Pi, and started minicom, and see this:

I would not mind this sh*t unless I had another case yesterday - I connected to the machine same way, but console appeared to be hung. Terminal port was receiving data at the machine's side when pressing buttons on Pi's keyboard, but sending nothing. Then I pressed ^C in the terminal window and machine rebooted (this is critical!).
I just performed a test - as I can access console properly, I do disconnect of minicom (^A Q), shut down Pi, disconnect it from the mains, wait 30 seconds, connect back it to mains, power up, start minicom, and voila... pressing enter key in console gives no response, however no tons of '@'. Recalling past experience, I press ^C, and then it said "Please press enter to activate console".
What makes console stuck somewhere when I power cycle terminal Pi? And that are the source of '@' characters (seemingly accumulating with time)? Some process trying to hijack console port from machine side and sh*tting there?
Update: if I just close minicom and wait some time, then connect with it nothing bad happens, console is immediately asking for activation and user name (edit: no, it does NOT ask for activation). Therefore there must be something about either Pi being physically unavailable (turned off) or miscommunication of machine on the dead communication RX/TX (TTL-version) serial port.
Update: same with picocom after power cycle of Pi. But ^@ are displayed only after I pressed enter after it displayed "Terminal ready"

Update: looking at the machine's serial port activity using /proc/tty/driver/serial
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5623244 rx:4462215 fe:378 brk:4461777 oe:5 RTS|DTR

after Pi powerdown
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5717394 rx:4540271 fe:567 brk:4539644 oe:8 RTS|DTR

after mains plugin
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5750738 rx:4568356 fe:567 brk:4567729 oe:8 RTS|DTR

at RPi OS logo
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5773072 rx:4583488 fe:567 brk:4582861 oe:8 RTS|DTR

after picocom start
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5773072 rx:4583488 fe:567 brk:4582861 oe:8 RTS|DTR

after I press enter in picocom
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:139 tx:5776904 rx:4583489 fe:567 brk:4582861 oe:8 RTS|DTR

What does it show... RPi sends something to the wires after it was released by picocom. WTH? RPi sends something into the wires when it starts. And then in picocom when I press enter key machine responds with ~3000 characters.
During this power cycle machine receives 121274 characters of something from RPi and sends 149828 + 3832 characters.
Update: As @phuclv advised I performed reading of console on the machine using hexdump -C /dev/ttyS0 > /tmp/txt.txt. Unfortunately it is not that good test because port does not receive characters to perform flush to hexdump, and hexdump only have shown 79 bytes when I pressed enter key in picocom - when I stopped hexdump using ^C on machine (therefore some unflushed data was lost):
# cat /tmp/txt.txt
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

Therefore yes, picocom/minicom session sends something to the serial port, and as they two do the same, it must not be them, it must be a driver.
I won't be surprised with such bug in driver as have seen the RS-485 devices hanging the bus during their reboot/reinitialization.
Update: so I have taken a scope to see what is going on the line, and have some interesting info.
During idle operating time the RPi's TX level is high (good). When I issue shutdown now command RPi pulls TX line down (break condition) and sends several bursts of sh*t:

You can see the levels are between 0.6V and 1.21 V, crossing 0.8 V TTL low level definition into the TTL gray area. This pic shows one burst, I have seen three in a row with 1 second time distance. Picture shows 12 ms of the noise (or what is it) which is a lot of data @ 115200 baud.
When I unplug the RPi from the mains it has the following:

which is not a big issue from logic point of view - TX line is being released.
When I put mains back:

This one is really bad, RPi's serial port is unable to power up properly (not start with software or with its configuration - but electrically start).
Therefore my conclusion is I found the bug in RPi serial port design. This is RPi4 Model B.
Update: I performed some more tests. Disconnected RPi from the machine, measuring port open ended. Power up issue still present, but there're no more bursts after shutdown now. Ground, of course, is connected between the devices, and during shutdown I do not plug or unplug anything, therefore the source of this noise on RPi TX line is not clear. This definitely needs deeper investigation. For now I just keep this behavior in mind, and will plan not to use serial port for console in production.

Do you have a pull up resistor on the Tx and Rx lines? It's probable when the Pi turns off it let's it's Tx line float down to ground as it has no power to pull it up. That would explain lots of received NULL characters. A weak pull up may help stop that, though you'd have to check if the pi is tolerant of voltage on its IO lines when powered off - if not a buffer would be needed.

^@ represents the NUL byte (0x00, much like ^A represents 0x01).
Minicom on its own does not show received control characters this way, so they're most likely echoed back in this format by the getty (login prompter) on the remote side.
This means that either the Pi is sending NUL characters or they're somehow showing up on the wire, and the software on H3 echoes each of them as an ASCII ^@.

thanks. sounds very logical. I tried picocom (edited question) - same issue!

you can easily see the raw bytes on the tty with cat -v /dev/tty... or any tools that read directly from the file, no need for a terminal

@phuclv not sure I understand your statement. I need terminal to control machine, not just sending something out there.
